# Restart Windows Service in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, windows-services

I got a link from SO [Cannot restart a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309990/cannot-restart-a-service-c) where it says to restart the windows service.

The way it should restart the service is mentioned in the question as

```
public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);

    int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
    if (!(service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) || service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
    {
        service.Stop();
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
    }
    // count the rest of the timeout
    int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
    timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));

    if (!(service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running) || service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)))
    {
        service.Start();
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
    }
}
```

But i am not sure here, as to where to write the code. I need to restart the windows service as soon as that is installed from my application

Let me know if any input is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "installed from my application"? If you use Windows Installer, derive a class from Installer. If you install manually, call RestartService right after your installation code. However, the RestartService is invoked from inside your application.

Comment: @sprinter252: When i install my windows (desktop) application, the service gets installed in services.msc. After that i wish to restart once. How to do that?

Comment: Why not use net start after installing.

Comment: @James: Not sure what you mean by "net"?

Comment: net start can be called from the command line, which is were I assume you install the service?

Comment: James is talking about this: http://ss64.com/nt/net_service.html

Comment: @James/@Jonas: I got what you mean.you mean to restart the service from external command. but i wish to that from C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I simply use `net start` and `net stop` to restart services. Example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public static void RestartService(string serviceName)
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("net.exe", "stop " + serviceName);
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    psi.UseShellExecute = true;
    psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory;
    var st = Process.Start(psi);
    st.WaitForExit();

    psi = new ProcessStartInfo("net.exe", "start " + serviceName);
    psi.UseShellExecute = true;
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory;
    st = Process.Start(psi);
    st.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: can we start stop the service from with in same service ?